# Redshift deployments without superuser access

Tags: amazon-redshift

Without using admin user (w/ superuser access) to deploy changes into redshift cluster, want to create a group which will have permissions to be able to deploy changes and that group can be assigned to deployment team. 
But looks like one cannot modify the views without being the owner of the view or being a superuser. Is there any way to accomplish deployments (which will include altering tables/updating existing views - without changing their ownership) without granting superuser access to development/devops teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using a stored procedure with [`SECURITY DEFINER`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-security-and-privileges.html).

[`sp_controlled_access`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_controlled_access.sql) provides an example of using `SECURITY DEFINER` to allow an unprivileged user to execute a query with the permissions of the SP creator. It uses an "auth" table to check whether the user has the authority to run the query submitted.

[`sp_check_primary_key`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_check_primary_key.sql) provides an example of a stored procedure that takes admin actions and logs the record of the actions in a table.

My recommendation would be to start with a very simple SP and enhance/extend it as you gain confidence and experience with Redshift stored procedures.

I would also recommend creating a number of test cases similar to the "Usage Example" section in these SPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the VIEWs/TABLEs from any user, and then grant `ALL` rights to those VIEWs/TABLEs using `GRANT ALL ON table_or_view_name TO deploy_user_or_group`, to deploy_user or a GROUP.

Comment: Doesn't work, altering objects is only allowed by the object owner or users with superuser access.